# Hello, i want to find a specific cell value from an excel using java...how can i get it?

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

[image: My ExcelSheet Image]

Here in the above excel i want to fetch the value according to the indicator id and the dateTime id.

Answer (score 0):

Since excel workbook is just a zip archive of XML files, you could approach it as such and parse XML belonging to the sheet you want with Java.
You can take a look yourself at the structure of the XML file if you add .zip extension to your file and go to xl > worksheets > sheet1.xml (or whatever the name of your sheet is).

Comment: actually i have set the numerators in the rows and dates in the columns. So i have to check specific values exist for specific numerator & date combination on specific date column(ex. Apr 2017).

Comment: Yes, you can read cells where these identifiers are written based on their value and known position (column and row IDs), and from combination of those decide target cell to read value from.

Comment: I am not a Java programmer, but from experience with other languages I guess you would use a `for` loop to iterate the XML nodes and few string functions to extract the information you need from it.